# Minecraft 1.9.2 Command /give converted to /summon

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm currently trying to convert a `/give` command into a `/summon` command.

```
/give @p minecraft:nether_star 1 0 {specialNetherStar:1b,display:{Name:"Nature"},ench:[{id:60s,lvl:10s}]}
```

Each time I convert it into this:

```
/summon Item ~ ~1 ~ {Item:{Id:minecraft:"nether_star",specialNetherStar:1b,display:{Name:"Nature"},ench:[{id:60s,lvl:10s}]}}
```

It ends up summoning a stone block instead. I do not understand why though. If someone could help me out I would be very grateful to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NBT data is case-sensitive. Instead of `Id` for the item format you need `id`.

All tags that are not the root `id`, `Damage`, `Count`, or `Slot`, must be placed within a single `tag` compound. The NBT input for `/give` is already starting within the `tag` compound because the root data (apart from `Slot`, which cannot be used with `/give`) is already specified in the command's syntax.

You will also want to place the quotation marks around the entire string "minecraft:nether_star" rather than just around the "nether_star" part, as the quotes will otherwise be a part of the value and will invalidate the item ID.

Keep in mind that without a `Count` tag specified, its value will default to 0 and the item cannot be picked up.

Fixed command, adding a count of 1:

```
/summon Item ~ ~1 ~ {Item:{id:"minecraft:nether_star",Count:1b,tag:{specialNetherStar:1b,display:{Name:"Nature"},ench:[{id:60s,lvl:10s}]}}}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me again Skylinerw. I understand what parts I have mess up and how to correct it.